# How to use mutually exclusive flags in your shell and add an optional argument flag ( stuck with getopts)

Tags: shell, awk, case, command-line-arguments, getopts

I am using a standard getopts logic. But I want to how I can make the options I offer- mutually exclusive. 
e.g.

```
shell.sh -a SID 
                              <accepted>
shell.sh -b SID
                              <accepted>
shell.sh -ab SID 
               Message- using ab together is the same as running shell.sh     without   any   options supplying  just SID . Help usage < ya da ya > 
shell.sh 
                Please enter SID at the minimum. Usage < ya da ya >
shell.sh SID
               <accepted>
```

I am trying to develop this logic using something like below

```
while getopts ":a:b:" opt; do
  case $opt in
  a ) SID="$OPTARG";;
      set var=1
  b ) SID="$OPTARG";;
      set var=2

 \?) echo "Invalid option: -"$OPTARG"" >&2
        exit 1;;
  ) echo "Option -"$OPTARG" requires an argument." >&2
        exit 1;;
  esac
done

If  (( val == 1 ))  then ; # option a is invoked SID supplied 
<stuff>
elif  (( val == 2 )) then ; # option b is invoked SID supplied 

<stuff>

else # SID supplied but neither a or b is invoked 
<stuff>
fi
```

How do enforce  mutually exclusive flags. I a sure there are more acrobat ways to do it. I think I am missing something  commonsense here - and trying to figure that out .
Thx

```
$ more opt.ksh
die () {
    echo "ERROR: $*. Aborting." >&2
    return  1
}

var=
while getopts ":a:b:" opt; do
  case $opt in
      a ) SID="$OPTARG"
          [ "$var" = 2 ] && die "Cannot specify option a after specifying option b"
          [ "$OPTARG" = b ] && die "Do not specify b as a value for option a"
          var=1
          ;;
      b ) SID="$OPTARG"
          [ "$var" = 1 ] && die "Cannot specify option b after specifying option a"
          [ "$OPTARG" = a ] && die "Do not specify a as a value for option b"
          var=2
          ;;
      :)  die "Must supply an argument to $OPTARG"
          ;;
      \?) die "Invalid option: -$OPTARG. Abort"
          ;;
  esac
done
shift $(($OPTIND - 1))
[ "$SID" ] || SID=$1
[ "$SID" ] || die "You must, at the minimum, supply SID"
```

I am using ksh

```
$ ps -p $$
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 1261 pts/45   00:00:00 ksh
```

1st time  I run it .

```
$ . opt.ksh -a 123 -b 123  # c0
ERROR: Cannot specify option b after specifying option a. Aborting.
-bash: /home/d1ecom1/gin1: No such file or directory


$ . opt.ksh -ab 123  # c1 should reject "cant use a and b togather. try with a or b"
-nologin: .[25]: shift: 4: bad number
$ . opt.ksh -a -b  # c2  same as c1's message
$ . opt.ksh -a -b 123 # c3 same as c1

$ . opt.ksh -a -b 123  # c5 
$ . opt.ksh -ab 123    # c6
$ . opt.ksh -a 123 -b 123  # c7
```

All above cases  C0:C7 should reject.  Notice C0 and C7 are the same. Yet inspite of this C0 gives the expected error and C7 will not give any  error ? strange

only ones to work should be

```
. opt.ksh -a 123
. opt.ksh -b 123
. opt.ksh  123
```

@hvd :TYSM  for your reply.
I would like to add an additonal flag -p that will give a "path override" option.
so maybe we have to extend getopt to take parameters like this

```
    die () {
    echo "ERROR: $*. Aborting." >&2
    exit 1
}

var=
opta=false
optb=false
while getopts ":ab:p" opt; do
  case $opt in
      a ) $optb && die "Cannot specify option a after specifying option b"
          opta=true
          ;;
      b ) $opta && die "Cannot specify option b after specifying option a"
          optb=true
          ;;
      p )  [ -d "$mypath" ] && die "path is invalid"

          ;;

      \?) die "Invalid option: -$OPTARG. Abort"
          ;;
  esac
done
shift $(($OPTIND - 1))
test $# -eq 0 && die "You must supply SID"
test $# -eq 1 || die "Too many command-line arguments"
# SID=$1
```

The above was the old approach. Now I have 2 Input parameters. One is the SID and the other is the path. Is it as simple as the above or do I need to add more checks to prevent other unwanted combinations.  The question I guess I am trying to aim at is , what more provisions would need to be made to allow this -p parameter which is an optiona override parameter. - p can co-exist with any parameter above but then I guess one requirement is that it should be immediately following the -p flag
so this should not allow - because its not clear .

```
shell.sh -b -p 123 /home/yadaya
```

Thanks again

Comment: Why are you treating SID an an option argument? If you simply make `-a` and `-b` options that do not take any arguments (by dropping the `:`), and always check whether a non-option was supplied as the SID, this would already work as expected.

Comment: Updated the post with those results. Still stuck

Comment: You do need that the first and third line of that last part (`shift $(($OPTIND - 1))` / `[ "$SID" ] || die "You must, at the minimum, supply SID"`) that you've now turned into comments, in order to reject `-a` by itself. I'll expand my approach into an answer in a short while.

Comment: I actually want to add an additional -p /path flag. I updated my Q.Whenever you get a chance.Thx

Comment: That's something that you should probably ask as a new question, not as an edit of your old question. But, unlike your `-a`/`-b`, that does seem to me like it would work well as an option argument (`:abp:`, not `:ab:p`). In your `p)` case, just set `mypath=$OPTARG` (and validate as needed). The rest of the checks would remain the same, because you would still only have one non-option argument. However, while `-p /path -a 123` seems clearly valid and would be allowed, so would `-a -p /path 123`, yet `-a 123 -p /path` would be rejected. You can decide if that makes sense to you.

Comment: Hi Thx. `-a 123 -p /path` ( that last one )- does'nt that too seem valid because , long as the value for -p immediately follows it.Shell can make sense of it. What'll   confuse the shell is something like `-a -p 100 /path` because now I switched the values.Its combinations like these that I want to weed out..or maybe I am looking at it far too closely and I can assume that whoever will run , in all common sense wont test all the  wrong cases

Comment: With my suggested approach, `-a 123 -p /path` wouldn't be valid because `123` is a non-option argument, and non-option arguments cannot be followed by options. `-a -p 100 /path` would be caught by your check that the argument for `-p` must be a valid path, so long as the user doesn't do `mkdir 100`. And if the user does create that directory, then `100` would be a valid argument for `-p`.

Comment: the other q I had was regarding -p ( I can ask another Q- just let me know). I need to validate 2 things - p is defined and also p is a valid path would something like  `( [ -z $OPTARG ] && [ -d "$OPTARG" ] ) || die "message" ` work . I want both these conditions true or else die .Maybe you can help write that better. thanks again

Comment: I'm confused. Can you give an example where `[ -d "$OPTARG" ]` returns a success code that you want to reject?

Comment: I am telling it 1st I want to make sure you have a value ( the -p switch ) by the `-z` option and then check if that value is a valid directory. I had the idea that `-d` would check that. Maybe I gross on the syntax . How else would I say it . ( value is present && its a valid directory ) or else die .

Comment: An empty string is not a valid directory, so `[ -d "$OPTARG" ]` should already handle that case, and for me, it does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how you can do it without making SID an option argument, which makes more sense to me:

```
die () {
    echo "ERROR: $*. Aborting." >&2
    exit 1
}

var=
opta=false
optb=false
while getopts ":ab" opt; do
  case $opt in
      a ) $optb && die "Cannot specify option a after specifying option b"
          opta=true
          ;;
      b ) $opta && die "Cannot specify option b after specifying option a"
          optb=true
          ;;
      \?) die "Invalid option: -$OPTARG. Abort"
          ;;
  esac
done
shift $(($OPTIND - 1))
test $# -eq 0 && die "You must supply SID"
test $# -eq 1 || die "Too many command-line arguments"
SID=$1
```

The changes I've made are:

- `return 1` becomes `exit 1` (unrelated to your question, but `die` sounds like it shouldn't continue). `return 1` would merely make the `die` function return non-successfully, but the calls to `die` don't check its result, it would carry on regardless.
- The `getopts` string is `:ab` instead of `:a:b:`. No matter how you call your script, you always need to pass exactly one SID, regardless of options, so it doesn't make sense to me to include it as part of the options.
- The options are stored in boolean `opta` and `optb` variables for easier checking
- After all options are passed, the remaining command-line arguments are counted. Unless it's exactly one, the call to the script is invalid.

All your valid calls in the question are accepted, all the invalid ones are rejected. One note of interest about this, though: your test case c7 (`-a 123 -b 123`) is expected to fail, and does fail, but not because `-a` and `-b` are combined. Instead, in my approach, since `-b` appears after a non-option argument, it itself is a non-option argument, and the reason for rejecting it becomes "Too many command-line arguments".

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications. The exit 1 kicks me out of the shell : ( !!. If I use return it behaves wonky

Comment: @user1874594 Right, that's because you're calling it with `.` instead of a separate shell (as is more common for scripts like this). `return` has no meaningful effect here, since you ignore the exit status of the `die` function. It would work if you call it as `ksh opt.ksh [args]`, and it's a bit more complicated and beyond what I think your question is really about to get it working properly for the `.` form too.

Comment: TY. So I'd just +x it and exe it directly then. Let me try and update TY again

Comment: TY. So I'd just +x it and exe it directly then. Let me try and update TY again . Works like a charm. V helpful  learning. TY

Answer (score 5):

For a case where you *must* specify exactly one of options `-s`, `-i` or `-h`, and where you have two more options `-v` and `-n` which are optional, you could do something like the following:

```
modes=0
while getopts :vs:i:h:n opt; do
  case "$opt" in
    v)
      verbose='non-empty-string-true-flag'
      ;;
    s)
      ((modes++))
      : do something with OPTARG, the s form
      ;;
    i)
      ((modes++))
      : do something with OPTARG, the i form
      ;;
    h)
      ((modes++))
      : do something with OPTARG, the h form
      ;;
    n)
      dryrun='non-empty-string-true-flag'
      ;;
    :)
      printf 'Option -%s requires an argument\n' "$OPTARG" >&2
      usage
      exit 1
      ;;
    *)
      printf 'Invalid option: -%s\n' "$OPTARG" >&2
      usage
      exit 1
      ;;
  esac
done
shift "$((OPTIND-1))"
if [ "$modes" -eq 0 ]; then
  printf "Missing required option\n" >&2
  usage
  exit 1
elif [ "$modes" -gt 1 ]; then
  printf "Error: -h, -i and -s are mutually exclusive and may only be used once\n" >&2
  usage
  exit 1
fi
```

This is excerpted from a script of mine, with the processing to be done on the `s`, `i` or `h` arguments omitted for simplicity of illustration.

The synopsis for the script looks like:

```
$0 [ -v ] [ -n ] { -i IPADDRESS | -h HOSTNAME | -s HOSTSHA }
```

Answer (score 2):

This makes options a and b mutually exclusive:

```
die () {
    echo "ERROR: $*. Aborting." >&2
    exit 1
}

var=
while getopts ":a:b:" opt; do
  case $opt in
      a ) SID="$OPTARG"
          [ "$var" = 2 ] && die "Cannot specify option a after specifying option b"
          [ "$OPTARG" = b ] && die "Do not specify b as a value for option a"
          var=1
          ;;
      b ) SID="$OPTARG"
          [ "$var" = 1 ] && die "Cannot specify option b after specifying option a"
          [ "$OPTARG" = a ] && die "Do not specify a as a value for option b"
          var=2
          ;;
      :)  die "Must supply an argument to $OPTARG"
          ;;
      \?) die "Invalid option: -$OPTARG. Abort"
          ;;
  esac
done
shift $(($OPTIND - 1))
[ "$SID" ] || SID=$1
[ "$SID" ] || die "You must, at the minimum, supply SID"
```

Note that optargs interprets `shell.sh -ab SID` as option `a` with argument `b` followed by `SID` as an argument to the script, not part of an option.   To detect that problem, the lines above involving `[ "$OPTARG" = b ] && die...` and `[ "$OPTARG" = a ] && die...` were added.

You wanted to accept `shell.sh SID` with no option specified.  This is handled by the first two lines after the case statement.

Comment: Hi TY for that innovative approach. It still does not work. I changed the exit in die to `return1 ` else it exiting my login .When I use `return  1` the results are totally unpredictable. i upated them in the Q above