# getopts checking for mutually exclusive arguments

Tags: bash, getopts

I have a simple script (below) that has mutually exclusive arguments.

The arguments for the script should be `./scriptname.sh -m|-d [-n]`, however, a user can run the script with `./scriptname.sh -m -d` which is wrong.

**Question**: how can I enforce that only one of the mutually exclusive arguments have been provided by the user?

```
#!/bin/sh

usage() {
   cat <<EOF
Usage: $0 -m|-d [-n]
where:
    -m create minimal box
    -d create desktop box
    -n perform headless build
EOF
   exit 0
}

headless=
buildtype=

while getopts 'mdnh' flag; do
  case "$flag" in
    m) buildtype='minimal' ;;
    d) buildtype='desktop' ;;
    n) headless=1 ;;
    h) usage ;;
    \?) usage ;;
    *) usage ;;
  esac
done

[ -n "$buildtype" ] && usage
```

Comment: Someone else has been asking this...hold on, I'll find it...Ah, there it is...[How to use mutually exclusive flags in your shell — stuck with `getopts`?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21695565/how-to-use-mutually-exclusive-flags-in-your-shell-stuck-with-getopts)  It was even in the list of related questions.  You could also look at [Using `getopts` in bash shell script to get long and short command line options](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/402377/using-getopts-in-bash-shell-script-to-get-long-and-short-command-line-options/).  That covers a lot of territory.

Comment: I did search on google and scan the recommended questions, but didn't think these links were relevant.  Hopefully, my question title will help others who are also inadequate at searching (like me) :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I can think of 2 ways:

Accept an option like `-t <argument>` Where argument can be `desktop` or `minimal`

So your script will be called as:

```
./scriptname.sh -t desktop -n
```

OR

```
./scriptname.sh -t minimal -n
```

**Another alternative** is to enforce validation inside your script as this:

```
headless=
buildtype=

while getopts 'mdnh' flag; do
  case "$flag" in
    m) [ -n "$buildtype" ] && usage || buildtype='minimal' ;;
    d) [ -n "$buildtype" ] && usage || buildtype='desktop' ;;
    n) headless=1 ;;
    h) usage ;;
    \?) usage ;;
    *) usage ;;
  esac
done
```

Comment: Many thanks!  Btw - I noticed and fixed a typo in the question, `buildttype` should have been `buildtype`.

Comment: How to adapt the code if the 2 options are no mandatory, but if used, should be used only one. My code is similar but my variable is not empty as default, it is `dir=pwd` and the options `m` or `d` would redefine it.

Comment: Thankyou for the answer, but could you explain further why [ -n "$buildtype" ] validates these to be mutually exclusive?

Comment: `-n "$buildtype"` will return success if `$buildtype` is non-empty.